# How to implode foreach

Tags: php, foreach, implode

**How to implode `foreach()` with comma?**

```
foreach($names as $name) {
    //do something
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $name .'</a>';
}
```

Want to add comma after each link, except the last one.

Comment: Mmh what is the point in having a lot of links with different names but the same URL?

Comment: Felix, are you a mind reader who can see what's behind "//do something"? :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Raveren's solution is efficient and beautiful, but here is another solution too (which can be useful in similar scenarios):

```
$elements = array();
foreach($names as $name) {
    //do something
    $elements[] = '<a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $name .'</a>';
}
echo implode(',', $elements);
```

Comment: In general, this one should be faster than concatenating strings. This would probably be even faster if the string was built using either string formatting or variable substitution: `$elements[] = "<a href=\"$url\" title=`...

Comment: This one's slower though and is neither more readable nor functional. (not that it's worse, I'm just defending the micro-optimization)

Comment: @Blixt, that's just a guess, I can't find the source, but concat and substr was benchmarked to be faster in all cases.

Comment: True, it's just a guess, but generally, string formatting is more elegant too, so I wouldn't consider it a bad change even if it was slower. Also, an array of strings that is concatenated is, to me, more readable than stripping off the last character.

Comment: Bingo McBingo, did the trick for me, simplest way to get that darned comma in to an existing foreach loop

Answer (score 12):

You need to transform your array instead of iterating using foreach. You can do this with [`array_map`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

**PHP 5.3 syntax with closures**

```
echo implode(", ", array_map(function($name) use($url, $title)
{
    return '<a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $name .'</a>';
}, $names));
```

**Compatible syntaxe before PHP 5.3**

```
function createLinkFromName($name)
{
    return '<a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $name .'</a>';
}
echo implode(", ", array_map('createLinkFromName', $names));
```

**PHP 5.3 syntax with a better reability**

```
function a_map($array, $function)
{
    return array_map($function, $array);
}

echo implode(", ", a_map($names, function($name) use($url, $title)
{
    return '<a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $name .'</a>';
}));
```

Comment: Frankly this borders on unreadable - especially with such a trivial task. Also it's most probably the slowest solution if you're into performance.

Comment: I wanted to propose the same, but you have to be careful with `$url` and `$title`. They won't be set (at least in the before PHP 5.3 example).

Comment: Isn't this far more complicated than necessary?

Comment: It is not that complicated, unreadability comes from the array_map syntax that puts the function first which is not a wise decision when working with closures. I suggest defining a new function with the opposite order of arguments to improve readbility.

Answer (score 3):

```
$first = TRUE;
foreach($names as $name) {
    //do something
    if(!$first) { echo ', '; }
    $first = FALSE;
    echo '<a href="', $url, '" title="', $title, '">', $name, '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Micro-optimisation: with echo, use commas instead of string concatenation: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-echo-commas-vs-concatenation/

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($names as $name) {
    //do something
    $str .= '<a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $name .'</a>,';
}
echo substr($str,0,-1);
```

EDIT:
as the comments point out, this way of doing things is a little error prone if you change the separator (precisely its length) and forget the substr parameter. So use the foreach method unless performance is absolutely critical.

Comment: why, this is faster than implode.

Comment: … until you change the separator and forget to adjust the `substr`.

Comment: @janmoesen that's very valid. Not a reason to give me a minus though :/

Comment: Sorry, I was not giving you specifically a minus; just this approach. I've seen it too many times: building a query this way and then `substr`ing it into syntax errordom. I am trying to discourage this approach when there is a cleaner way with `implode`.

Comment: @reinis, wtf are you even talking about? `>So use the foreach method unless performance is absolutely critical.` Please recall the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
$s = '';
foreach ($names as $name) {
  if ($s) $s .= ', ';
  $s .= '<a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $name . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: i think you meant `if(!$s)`, or better `if(strlen($s) == 0) $s = ', ';`

Comment: knittl, you can save a function call by checking isset($s[0]) instead of strlen \o/

Comment: No. `if ($s)` is correct. We don't want to start with a comma. We want to add one only from the second link on.

Comment: But you managed to confuse me enough to edit my answer and then revert it.

Comment: oh ok, i didn't realize you were using $s for both the delimiter and the string itself. sorry for the caused confusion

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ugly solution using echo:

```
 $total = (count($names) - 1 );

 foreach($names as $i => $name) 
 {
      if($i != $total) 
           echo '<a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $name .'</a>, ';
      else
           echo '<a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $name .'</a>';
 }
```

Comment: I would +1, except that counting the array on every iteration is quite wasteful (especially if the array is sizable)...  Perhaps pre-compute (`$numOfElements = count($names) - 1; foreach ...`)...